# Roster and List - are they synonyms

Tags: meaning

I am not native speaker of English. Today I came across this word "roster" and want to understand it better. According to the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roster), roster means:

- a list of the people or things that belong to a particular group,
  team, etc.
- a group of people or things whose names are included on a roster
- a list that shows the order in which a job or duty is to be done by
  the members of a group

Can I say: roster of books = list of books, roster of types = list of types, roster of students = list of students?

Comment: @Chappo Yes, I looked up - see #1 http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roster and don't understand why my question is downvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between a list and a roster is that a roster contains names, whereas a list can contain names but does not have to. The general usage of these words is also different. A list is usually used in the context where one needs to group elements related together in a way. A roster is usually used in the context where one needs to assign duties to people at specific times.

Below is a list of yoghurt companies by market share.

[image]

Below is a roster

[image]

**Edit as at 8/8/17 2:44AM GMT+10**

I will also add a few more things to consider:

A list is usually one-dimensional: you have a list heading, and under it list items. A roster is multi-dimensional.

In a roster, each intersection represents a unique value, an instance. In a list, an instance is only a list item. In a roster, the order is generally not important. In a list, the order may have some meaning.